# Does OCL work with composite structure diagrams?

Tags: uml, ocl

Is OCL meant to be used in combination with a composite structure diagram?

Or does it not make sense? If it makes sense, could someone give a quick example for a possible OCL constraint, e.g. based on this example diagram [source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/uml-20-in/0596007957/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages187407.png) ?

[image]

Comment: OCL doesn't work with diagrams, it is used on Elements. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @GeertBellekens If we take the composite structure diagram linked above, I would like to constrain for example: "If the MainWindow's title is "My XOR App", then there is either an OkButton or a CancelButton (exclusive or).

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't be able to post such image, it looks like fair use to me (if such diagram can be even copyrighted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML specifically mentions such situation (section 7.6. of specs)

[image]

Constraints themselves can be attached to any kind of UML `Element`, or in fact a collection of Elements.

[image]

And finally:

> 7.2.1
>
> The root concepts of Element and Relationship provide the basis for all other modeling concepts in UML.

Which means that you can add constraint to anything.

Comment: And if the diagram was a composite structure diagram such as the one I linked in my question? @GeertBellekens points out in his comment that OCL works with elements (not diagrams). This makes me think that you can write OCL constraints for all kinds of models / model diagrams. What do you think?

Comment: You should **define** the OCL constraints on the classes. They are then **validated** on the instances.